# Firebase remove a key from ref inside a js loop (web)

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to remove a selected child with a button from a reference inside the HTML Output.

The key is a chat message or a post.

Now I want, that the user can delete the selected message/post with a button.

I can delete all, but not exactly the selected child.

The Results and Content comes from a " for in " loop.

Delete selected (child) with Angular and AngularFire is no problem, but I want this without angular.

```
// get ref
var dbRef = firebase.database().ref().child("user/chat");

// child added
dbRef.on("child_added", function(snapshot) {
var newPost = snapshot.val();

// Loop / Results

for(var prop in newPost){
var xxx = "<li>
<p>"+newPost.content+"</p>
<button class='delete' id='deleteThis'> X </button>
</li>";
$(xxx).appendTo("#ul-result");    
}

// delete Post with button from above

$('#deleteThis').on('click', function(){
// delete all posts --- work
// dbRef.remove();

// delete only this post --- ?
dbRef.child('?').remove();

});
});
});
```

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lsfYX.jpg)

Comment: Your question is pretty confusing, can you clarify please. Also remove code that doesn't have to do with the question.

Comment: Sorry. I'm really trying to understand your code, but can't figure out how it's supposed to work. Iterating over the children of a snapshot with `for in` is **highly** suspicious. A more common pattern is to iterate with `snapshot.forEach(function(child) { ...`. The solution to your question is in two-steps: *1)* add the key of the post to the HTML you generate for that post, *2)* read the key back when the user clicks on the button and then delete the correct child.

Comment: Ok, "suspicious" :) ,,it works for me, but i think you're right, i'll take snapshot.forEach . But why is it no problem to delete the current key with angular over a iteration loop/repeat ??? without set & get the current key value. I want to keep it simple/ less, but when it doesn't be possible i set & read the key back. Thanks for that possibility!

Comment: I have improved the formulation of the question slightly and added a screenshot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few things you can do.  First, it seems like you're going to have multiple buttons with the `id` of `deleteThis`, when each `id` should be unique.  So instead, you may want to add the click handler to `.delete`.  Second, as someone else mentioned, you should use `snapshot.forEach` to iterate over the children.  Finally, when you create the buttons, you can add the key of the post as a data attribute:

```
<button class='delete' data-key='" + newPost.key + "'> X </button>
```

Then in your click handler you can use that key to target that specific post:

```
$('.delete').on('click', function(){
  var id = "user/chat/" + this.dataset.key;
  firebase.database().ref(id).remove();
});
```

Comment: IT WORK'SS--ZZ--TOP!!!! THX A lot Adrice & Frank ! Perfect ::))) ps (the second way with the forEach and datakey method. I am really grateful to you!